Unable to install jimp library through npm bcz of vulnerabilities checks
phin  <3.7.1 Severity: moderate phin may include sensitive headers in subsequent requests after redirect - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-x565-32qp-m3vf fix available via npm audit fix --forceWill install jimp@0.3.11, which is a breaking change node_modules/phin load-bmfont  >=1.4.0 Depends on vulnerable versions of phin node_modules/load-bmfont @jimp/plugin-print  >=0.4.0 Depends on vulnerable versions of load-bmfont node_modules/@jimp/plugin-print @jimp/plugins  >=0.4.0 Depends on vulnerable versions of @jimp/plugin-print node_modules/@jimp/plugins jimp  >=0.4.0 Depends on vulnerable versions of @jimp/plugins node_modules/jimp
5 moderate severity vulnerabilities

tried updated node version to latest which didn't help
tried installing jimp lower version which didn't help
Tried npm audit fix --force which didn't help

How can i install this library ?

Please EDIT your question so that the formatting is readable.  Hint: use the preview window to see what it looks like before submitting the update.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Just add to your package.json:
"overrides": {
  "phin": "^3.7.1"
}

so your package.json should look like:
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {...}
  "overrides": {
    "phin": "^3.7.1"
  }
}

and run npm i
